# How to make bevel square with bevel curve?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to make a bevel square that will be used in a grid.

[image]

I want the following results controlled by two parameters:

[image]

`Bevel Amount = 0 / 0.5 / 1`
`Bevel Curve = 0`

[image]

`Bevel Amount = 0.5`
`Bevel Curve = -1 / 0 / 1`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working ...

[image]

Notes:

- *Math > Add* > Value 0.000001
- *Float Curve* > X 0.25, Y 0.75
- for each *Group Input* socket you can setup *Default / Min / Max* values, like you mentioned *Bevel Min* 0 *Max* 1 and *Curve* *Min* -1 *Max* 1).

[image]