# How to make gradient based bevel square?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I want to create bevel squares based on gradient values. I mean the corner of bevel should be a gradient value (if it makes sense).

Related to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308710/how-to-make-bevel-square-with-bevel-curve/308716#308716)

Let's say I have these gradients in a grid.

[image]

This is the result I want which is based on gradient value.

[image]

As you can see the lower right grid cell is white so the bevel is even on all the corners, similarly the top left grid cell has a darker bottom left corner so the bevel edge is smaller.

Comment: Hi, Karan .. is the lower illustration an example of what you want? It's not clear how  the gradient relates... perhaps you could model an example in geometry to show us what you want, in shaders

Comment: Are you using Cycles? What about OSL custom nodes?

Comment: No, but if the result needs cycles and OSL I am ok.

Comment: @Karan : take the Beveled Square and subtract the secondary gradient. you migh want to clamp the result, if needed. You can also use the Multiply operator, but that will scale the first texture, while Add will just move it (in the Z axis).